# NONE type not turning into 0's with fillna()

Tags: python, nonetype

I have this data column in a data frame that is of type object because some of the values are NONE. i tried turning them into 0's with fillna not workind. tried turning it into series - it still didnt work and not sure how to approach it next..

Answer (score 0):

```
dataframe.['your column name'].replace('NONE', np.nan, inplace=True)
dataframe.fillna(0)
```